# How do you enforce width on a webpage?

Tags: html, css

So I recently started creating some Webpages in my freetime and I was wondering how I can create a list that normally has a distance of like 95 pixels to the its next element to automatically detect if the window you're using gets smaller and thus decrease the distance to a certain minimum. Another solution would be to enforce a minimum width for the webpage but I couldn't find a way to do that either. The current problem for me is that I have 2 headers, and whenever I make the page small enough, it creates a new line with 1 word of the 2nd header.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito|PT+Serif+Caption|Heebo" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='header'>
        <h1>This is my homepage welcome!</h1>
        <nav id='nav'>
            <ul>
                <li>
                <a href='#'>My Life</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href='#'>My Skills</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href='#'>My Hobbys</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href='#'>My Qualifications</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class='container'>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    background: #222;
    color: white;
    text-align:center;
} 

h1{
    font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#nav {
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    background: LightGrey;
    position: absolute;
}

#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}

#nav ul li a {
    color: grey;
    font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin: 50 ;
    width: 500px;
}

.container{
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/mountain_lake_landscape_reflection_86115_3840x2400.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind making a snippet out of your code? This will help us to try out things on your example.

Comment: What you describe is called 'Responsive Design', and it usually involves 'CSS Media Queries'. Too big a subject to explain here, but if you search both these terms on e.g. YouTube then I'm sure you will find more tutorials than you could ever imagine.

Comment: I was just playing around with general resizing webpages, just like you said with Responsive Design. I haven't had any tutorials on that I so basically was just googling my ideas and playing around with that. I'll look up what you mentionend when I get back home from work so thank you very much. -- Now, what I wanted to achieve is a generally resizing homepage where the "nav" bar boxes (My life, My Skills...) would also be resizable that means when I make the Window bigger the margin gets bigger and when smaller the opposite BUT only to a certain point in which a scrollbar would be created.

Answer (score 1):

Links are `inline` elements. Adding `display: inline-block` will make them have box model:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: #ccf;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

Comment: Okay I understand what you mean. Thanks for the answer, the problem wouldn't be changed with that though, it would still create a new line for the My Qualifications box if the browser was made small enough. I played around with it abit and changed the width from 100% at #nav , .header and .container to 1080 pixels and now it works just fine. Not quite sure why it does that but now it's exactly how I wanted. Working with pixels is weird for different scales of monitors I suppose but it'll have to work for now.